# Cannot call member function, tried to do it properly still fails

Tags: c++, oop

I implemented a new class (ProtoType) in my header file. Which looks like this:

```
class ProtoType : public Test
{
    public:
        uint32_t test();


};

class RealProtoType : public Real
{
    public:
        uint32_t real();


};
```

Then in C++ file I made this

```
uint32_t ProtoType::test()
{
    return 5;
}

uint32_t RealProtoType::real()
{

    uint32_t holder = ProtoType::test();

}
```

Then I get this error when compiling

> error: cannot call member function ‘uint32_t ProtoType::test()’
>   without object    uint32_t ProtoType::test();

But I still fail, how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Since `ProtoType::test()` is a non-static member function you need an object of type `ProtoType` to call the function upon:

```
uint32_t RealProtoType::real()
{
    ProtoType foo;
    uint32_t holder = foo.test();
    return 42;
}
```

Comment: Okay I will test it when I am back home, but if I change the uint32_t to something else, would it have a new standard or can it be defined the same way?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say.

Comment: Basically I mean if I change the functions to example bool ProtoType::test(), do I use the same method to do it?

Comment: @GunnarErikson Yes.

Comment: Ok thanks will test it asap and tell you if it worked so others can benefit from it too